# Neverending tag problem

Tags: tags, errors

I'm having an issue with post tagging on a site. Every time I enter a tag, it becomes part of the same endless string. Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you [turned on debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: I haven't, it's a live site, it seems to recommend using this only on development sites. After weeks of fixing things left over from the rookie theme developer, I'm trying to figure out another way around this problem.

Comment: There's `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` - on live sites you can set `debug_display` to false and [`debug_log`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) to true so no errors show up in the front end and instead get dumped into a `debug.log` file. By seeing the full error it will be much easier to track down the issue.

Comment: Okay, haven't done this before, but I'm jumping in - thanks for the advice!

Comment: Looks like a bad filter to me. Search the "rookie theme developer"'s code for `add_filter` or maybe `add_action`

Comment: Hmm. Those are both present in 20 or more php files. This is something that cropped up recently, after restoring from a backup. I'll keep rooting around. Perhaps something perfect for one of the new ala carte WP fix sites.